# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Log(main) on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

Came back to VS Code after a while and I'm met with the following error in Log(Main):

```
[error] Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:109:7068)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

In the bar at the bottom it says: Internet not connected or can't connect to GitHub. In the Recommended box under Extensions it says We cannot connect to the Extensions Marketplace at this time, please try again later.

Firefox, Chrome and Edge can connect fine as can VS Code on a XUbuntu Virtualbox on the same machine, but I am having similar problems with Discord and Signal Desktop: failed connections due to ECONNRESET errors. The only thing I've found in common so far is that all 3 are Electron apps. Signal, just like beta versions of Discord I tried, only managed to connect once.

Things I've tried:

- disabling ExpressVPN/Windows Firewall/Kaspersky AV (free)
- full scan with Kaspersky and MalwareBytes
- changing DNS settings from automatic to Google to CloudFlare
- ipconfig release-renew-flushdns-registerdns
- netsh winsock reset
- windows system file checker
- reset home network

I logged the issue on VS Code GitHub but they sent me here so I'm hoping someone can help me with this. Been losing my mind on this for days now and really hoping to avoid a fresh install.

Edit1: I just tried safe mode with network and all problems seem to be solved. Not sure what this points to though... Faulty drivers, some conflicting startup service or program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel like a fool..
Turns out I didn't completely shutdown Kaspersky..