# Error Installing Python Extensions on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep getting the following error message:

```
2023-03-13 16:16:27.004 [error] net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET: Error:
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:105:7047)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (node:events:526:28)
```

I tried installing via extension manager.

Comment: can you install any other extension? What is the `extension manager`?

Comment: https://github.com/bitwarden/clients/issues/3279 which points to https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2398, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68396197/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73188759/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I have a Dell with "killer wifi acceleration", turned that off and everything is working now.

To answer prior questions. No I couldn't install any extensions and extension manager is the built in tool for doing what the name says...